# Mysql Server is down When Python Script is run

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

While i run python script to **scrape** new data and add to database then mysql server is down.
Any Suggestion

Comment: 'then mysql server is down' - not with you are you saying your script brought the server down or are you asking for a way to start the server with a python script?

Comment: in my script , i have insert statements in mysql  so i run that script my sql 2003 erorr.

Comment: Have you worked through https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Answer (score 0):

I think need more information to solve this for example sql log.

In my opinion, your statement is insert a huge data and server has not a correct configuration or your query should be split to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes i am inserting huge data .